Plesk on Ubuntu logs out
I have a problem with my plesk user, the question is that when X time passes, the user logs out and only happens to me with the administrator user. Other users do not have this problem.
For the inactivity session time is not, since it is a fairly high value that I specified at the time so that it does not happen to me, but even so, still closing the session. Some sessions are shorter than others, and sometimes it is as simple as logging in and automatically closing...
I am the only one with that user since it is a VPS server that I have private, what could happen?

Please post the above comment as an answer to your own question. After 24 hours you can click the big check beside your question to mark it as accepted.

It seems I found the answer, this is due to the change of ip during the session, it may be that my ISP changes this regularly, but since I tried the option to enable the change of IP during the session, I have not had an unexpected logout. plesk doc
